# Is there any example for Spring cloud Stream App Starters?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am learning the Spring cloud Stream App Starters at the moment, but the Spring.io official document is hard to understand and lack of fully examples, and I also hard to find anything I google it, so is there any place I could seek for an example for reference?

Please notice that I am talking about "**Spring cloud Stream App Starters**", not "**Spring cloud Stream**"

Comment: Spring "starters" are just library projects that define dependencies, so it's unclear what exactly you're looking for. Here's all the ones for spring boot https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters and here's Cloud Stream https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters

Answer (score -1):

I've just completed an example of Spring Cloud Stream based on Java Funtions

If you're interested in it, you could check it out in my repos via this link https://github.com/howiesynguyen/Java-basedExamples/tree/main/DemoSpringStreamWithJavaFuntions

Pls note that you may need a Kafka or Rabbitmq set up in order to run the example. If you choose Kafka, you can built a Docker Kafka image based on this one: https://github.com/howiesynguyen/Java-basedExamples/tree/main/DockerContainerizedKafka4Dev

Something you should also know. Since Spring Cloud version 2020.0.2 (Spring Cloud Stream v3.x), the following @EnableBinding, @Input, @Output, @StreamListener... annotations have been deprecated. Instead, Java Functions feature has been introduced to take advantage of functional programming model in Spring Cloud Stream v3.x. Spring Cloud Stream can bind directly to the input(s) and output(s) of a Function @Bean. The logical equivalence of the java.util.function types Supplier, Function, Consumer are mapped to the Spring Cloud Stream concepts Source, Processor, and Sink respectively

Hope that it could help

Comment: Hi Howie, I am not talking about "Spring Cloud Stream", I am talking about "Spring cloud Stream App Starters", they are a bit different, but I thinking you all the same